# How to retrieve all key-value pairs in a resource file located in App_GlobalResources

Tags: asp.net, resources

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I manage localized texts in .resx files located in `App_GlobalResources` folder.  I am able to retrieve any text value in any file knowing its key.

Now, I want to retrieve all key/value pairs in a particular resource file in order to write the result to some JavaScript.  A search revealed that I might be able to use [`ResXResourceReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) class and iterate through the pairs;  however the class is unfortunately located in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and I don't want to wire that dependency to my web app.  Is there any other way I can implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.  Now no need to reference Forms.dll.

```
public class ScriptController : BaseController
{
    private static readonly ResourceSet ResourceSet = 
        Resources.Controllers.Script.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CurrentCulture, true, true);

    public ActionResult GetResources()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("var LocalizedStrings = {");
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ResourceSet)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}: \"{1}\",", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
        builder.Append("};");
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        return Content(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no other answer.  Seems like referencing Forms.dll is the only way right now.  Here's the code I came up with.

```
public class ScriptController : BaseController
{
    private const string ResxPathTemplate = "~/App_GlobalResources/script{0}.resx";
    public ActionResult GetResources()
    {
        var resxPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format(ResxPathTemplate, string.Empty));
        var resxPathLocalized = Server.MapPath(string.Format(ResxPathTemplate, 
            "." + CurrentCulture));
        var pathToUse = System.IO.File.Exists(resxPathLocalized)
                            ? resxPathLocalized
                            : resxPath;

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(pathToUse))
        {
            builder.Append("var resources = {");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rsxr)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat("{0}: \"{1}\",", entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
            builder.Append("};");
        }
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        return Content(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```